# Lava lamp effect background Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the task of making a lava lamp effect on the background of my Flutter app. Can anyone tell me how to do it correctly?

Comment: Check out this project as an inspiration https://github.com/jamesblasco/flutter_lava_clock

Comment: Could you show your progress, what have you tried and did so far? StackOverFlow is not a website to request full features and is dedicated to help you with your progress, blockers, issues, etc

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For an app of mine, I had to use a `Stack` with two layers nested in a `Scaffold`: in one layer I put a looping video using the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package, and in the other layer the rest of the app, so that the video was visible in the background of any page of the app. This, of course, if you can get your hands on a lava-lamp video.

It's not the best solution though: the video stops if the user receives or makes a phone call, and I've had reports of it stopping without being able to pinpoint the reason. It's worth mentioning that I used this solution quite some time ago, so maybe there's a different solution available now. Still, I think it's worth a try.